# NSMutableDictionary doesn't get written to file

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I have NSMutableDictionary object say `obj`. When I write it to the disk using 
`[obj writeToFile:filename atomically:YES]` , the file does not get written to the disk. But the same set of statements work for a smaller mutable dictionary.

The first `obj` is `(nonatomic, retain)` property object of a class. The second smaller `obj` is a temporary local variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But the same set of statements work
>   for a smaller mutable dictionary.

That sets off a warning bell.  Namely, when you are attempting to write the large dictionary to disk, what is in it?  If you are using any of NSDictionary's file writing methods, they will only work with dictionaries that *only* contain instances of the classes blessed for use in property lists.

That is, if you have random other classes in there, the dictionary will not be written.  Doesn't matter of the classes support NSCoding or not.

If you need to persist a dictionary with non-property list classes, you'll either need to use NSCoding or, more likely better, use Core Data.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Have you checked that `obj` isn't `nil` by some accident?